# Как изменить значение параметра функции в JSP, чтобы заменить способ сортировки

Tags: java, сортировка, java-ee, jsp, jstl

У меня есть такой фрагмент кода, я хотел бы изменить способ сортировки (сейчас это `sortByTime`), но например, я хочу изменить на `sortByTitle` или `sortById`, как я могу это сделать?

Класс существует с некоторыми методами сортировки (**добавлю лишь метод 1 для краткости**)

```
public final class ListEntitySort {

    private static Comparator<Entity> compareByStartTime = Comparator.comparing(Entity::time);

    public static List<Event> sortByTime(List<Event> events) {
        events.sort(compareByStartTime);
        return events;
    }
... more 
}
```

Для сортировки в JSP странице я использую `function.tld`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<taglib
        xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-jsptaglibrary_2_1.xsd"
        version="2.1">

    <tlib-version>1.0</tlib-version>
    <short-name>Entity_Functions</short-name>
    <uri>ua.com.example</uri>

    <function>
        <name>sortByTime</name>
        <function-class>ua.com.example.web.command.functions.ListEntitySort</function-class>
        <function-signature>java.util.List sortByTime(java.util.List)</function-signature>
    </function>
  
    <function>
        <name>formatLocalDateTime</name>
        <function-class>ua.com.example.web.command.functions.Dates</function-class>
        <function-signature>java.lang.String formatLocalDateTime(java.time.LocalDateTime, java.lang.String)
        </function-signature>
    </function>

</taglib>
```

Что я делаю в сервлете єто получаю `list` и потом добавляю в сессию атрибут чтобы вывести на JSP странице

```
 List<Entity> entities = someService.getListEntities();
 request.setAttribute("entities", entities);
```

```
 <c:forEach var="entity" items="${p:sortByTime(entities)}">
                <tr>
                    <td>${entity.id}</td>
                    <td>${entity.title}</td>
                    <td>${entity.description}</td>
                    <td>${entity.location}</td>
                    <td>${p:formatLocalDateTime(entity.time, 'dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm')}</td>
                    <td>
 </tr>
```

Мои варианты:

Вероятно, создайте флаг, который отправит метод сортировки сервлету и изменит параметр метода сортировки для каждого.

Или может добавить скриплет в JSP и там как то прописать  `<%%>`,
или в JSP сделать что-нибудь с тегом `<c:if>` через JSTL.

```
<c:if test="${check the way of sorting }">
put here for each
</c:if>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете добавить параметр для изменения критерия

```xml
<function>
    <name>sortBy</name>
    <function-class>ua.com.example.web.command.functions.ListEntitySort</function-class>
    <function-signature>java.util.List sortBy(java.util.List, java.lang.String)</function-signature>
</function>
```

Тогда в JSP можно использовать параметр URL

```
<c:forEach var="entity" items="${p:sortBy(entities, param.sortBy)}">
            <tr>
                <td>${entity.id}</td>
                <td>${entity.title}</td>
                <td>${entity.description}</td>
                <td>${entity.location}</td>
                <td>${p:formatLocalDateTime(entity.time, 'dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm')}</td>
                <td>
             </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

Теперь поменять метод сортировки

```
public final class ListEntitySort {

    private static Comparator<Entity> compareByStartTime = Comparator.comparing(Entity::time);

    public static List<Event> sortBy(List<Event> events, String sortBy) {
        switch (sortBy) {
          case "time":
            events.sort(compareByStartTime);
            break;
          case ... more
         }        
        return events;
    }
... more 
}
```

Comment: да, сработало спасибо)